# PHP - Undifined index?

Tags: php, sql

The error:

Notice: Undefined index: image in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BEADERIE JEWELS/application/pages/necklaces/index.php on line 10

/>

The Query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products";  
$data = $connection->query( $query);    
$data->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
while ( $row = $data->fetchAll() ){
$products[] = $row; 
    }
```

The Html:

```
<?php foreach($products AS $product): ?>
<?php print_r($product); ?>
<div class="productbox">
<img src="site/Pictures/"<?php $product["image"]  ?>/>
<p><?php $product["price"]?></p>
```

print_r results: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [productname] => Bold Gold Necklace [description] => Gold chain Necklace [producttype] => necklace [image] => goldboldnecklace.jpg [stock] => 3 ) )

I tried adding isset() function but it didnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Semicolons after $product['blah'];

Comment: Why are you using multiple loops? Echoing can be easilly achievable using only one loop...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an array of products you're making an array containing an array of products.

Instead of `fetchAll` use `fetch` in your loop or simply assign `$products=$data->fetchAll()`

```
while ( $row = $data->fetch() ){
    $products[] = $row; 
}
```

or

```
$products = $data->fetchAll();
```

Comment: The fetch method works. Thanks. My image still doesnt show up though.

Comment: Not too sure about PHP anymore these days but shouldn't you use `echo $product["image"]` instead of only `$product["image"]`? Can you verify what output is actually generated? is `goldboldnecklace.jpg` mentioned in the generated HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Put $product[0]["image"] instead $product["image"].